# how to convert type of variable in CPLEX

Tags: cplex, relaxation

I have an Integer Linear Problem which is solved quickly when I change my variable type to double. now I'm developing a fix and relax algorithm and I used conversion to change data type which takes a long time. Does it mean that I made a mistake? how could I reduce the solving time?

Comment: By "conversion" do you mean instances of IloConversion (the Java class name)? If so, what is it that takes a long time: adding the conversions, deleting the conversions, or something else?

Comment: yes.that's it. I mean solving the problem takes along time when I add "conversion"

Comment: Are you converting from double to integer or from integer to double?

Comment: I'm converting from double to integer

Comment: When you say "takes a long time", you mean it takes CPLEX a long time to return from the command to add the conversions (as opposed to takes a long time to solve the converted model, which is to be expected)?